# how to submit object with list of sub-objects from JSP to Controller?

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I have a `class A` having field of `List` of `class B`

```
class A{

       private String x;
       private String y;
       private List<B> list;
}

class B{

      private string x1;
      private String y1;
}
```

In JSP, I have a form where there is input field `for x and y` and `c:foreach select for B`.

My question is that how to make a form so that i can pass a list of objects of type `B` inside `A` and send it to the spring controller.

So far i am getting a list with only one element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use array. example :

```
<c:forEach items="${a.list}" varStatus="i">
    <tr>
        <td><form:input path="list[${i.index}].x1" type="text" /></td>
        <td><form:input path="list[${i.index}].y1" type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

and for add and delete List rows in jsp i used javascript..

Comment: You are absolutely correct....javascript needs to come into the picture....i did it already......anyways thanks for your reply